# Traceback not showing in multithread context

Tags: python, multithreading

At the moment, I heavily rely on traceback to check python errors (on my console). However, the traceback is not output on the console when the error happens in a thread different from the main one:

```
def test(n):
    time.sleep(10-n)
    print(n)
    assert False


#assert False #if uncommented the console correctly show the traceback


with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
    res=executor.map(test,range(10))
print("DONE finally")
```

If I uncomment the "assert false" the traceback returned is the following one:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/massimo.bono/Documents/PythonWorkspace/AntaresPythonUtils/AntaresUtils/thread_try.py", line 14, in
>
> assert False
>
> AssertionError

If leave the comment, the output of the console is the following:

```
3
2
1
0
4
6
5
7
9
8
DONE finally

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Other infos useful to help me:

- I'm using python 3.4.3;
- my python console is the one embedded in PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.2
- I'm on windows 8.1 64bit;

I tried to run the same python file from the windows powershell by entering in the python console, but the traceback was not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understood it seems that the traceback of the threads still existed in the python runtime: they weren't simply printed on the stderr.

You can solve the issue by catching any exception in the method called by the executor, like this:

```
#this will be executed in a different thread. If any exception is caught
#it will be printed on the console
def thread_safe(n):
    try:
        test(n)
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()

with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
    res=executor.map(thread_safe,range(10))
print("DONE finally")
```